# SQL to HTML Table, new

Tags: php, html

I can't figure out why my code isn't working? When i run it the page is blank!

This is a Harry Potter Database. I am trying to put the data within my SQL Database in a HTML Table. Sounds easy but I can't figure out why my code is not working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Harry Potter Database </table>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Website </th>
    </tr>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "survey");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM result";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

if($res->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>". $row["ID"] . "</td>
        <td>". $row["Name"] . "</td>
        <td>". $row["Age"] . "</td>
        <td>". $row["Website"] . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "No RESULTS";
}
$conn->close();

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

result is the name data within my database called survey

> Undefined array key "ID" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ws5\sqlquery.php** on
> line **26**

This is the error in the source

Structure of Table

| ID | WEBSITE | AGE | WEBSITE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Please add the stucture of your table to your question.

Comment: What database engine are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL)?

Comment: I am using mySQL

Comment: Use dump_var($row); in order to debug the content of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows (where it looks like you are), MySQL stores all table and column names in lowercase by default (see [the docs for "Identifier Case Sensitivity" and `lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)).

That means that instead of `"ID"`, you should be using `"id"`, instead of `"Name"` it should be `"name"`, etc.

Comment: Ok, I now have no errors in the source code. But when I run the host page I have no table whatsover?

Comment: I also made a mistake with the heading! Such a noob mistake. I put table instead of title :(